# MATLAB insert values in array by looping

Tags: matlab, loops

This code gives me an error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

I'm reading frames starting with "a" from a folder then doing a quantization on each frame by looping, after quantization I want to put the first x and y in each frame in X_new array and Y_new array respectively.

```
count = 0;
for i = 1 : frames  
    b = imread(strcat('a',num2str(i),'.jpg'));
    numberOfGrayLevels = 2;
    quantizedImage = uint8(mat2gray(b) * (numberOfGrayLevels-1));
    [x y]= size(quantizedImage);
    [x y] = find(quantizedImage ~= 0)
    count=count+1;
    X_New(count) = x(1);
    Y_New(count) = y(1);
end
```

Comment: Your `quantizedImage` doesn't have any 0 values and therefore `find` returns empty arrays that you try to index using `x(1)` which causes your error. Step through and debug your code.

Comment: Also the `size` call is not required. You're not using the size of the image anywhere in the loop.... and this code does not perform any quantization at all.  Are you sure this code works?

Comment: You are right!!! there is some files in the folder that are all black and doesnt have any ones in it. I tried typing (i = i+5) in the end so the loop wont have to go over the whole files..but still it doesnt work at all..I dont know why.


The quantization is supposed to change all the values from around 255 to 1 and others to zero..It changes the grey pic into binary then I take the first one and save its x and y in an array.